# AngularJS Dropdown ng-if on ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building a twitter bootstrap list using angular's ng-repeat:

```
<ul class="dropdown dropdown-menu">
    <li class="menuOption" ng-repeat="option in options">
        <a data-ng-click="option.value>0 ? foo() : goo()">
        {{option.label}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to include a divider (`<li class="divider"></li>`) inside this list. It should be before the last element in the list (which is also indicated by `option.value` with a negative value, which is probably an easier indication).

My problem is that since the ng-repeat iteration is on the `li` element itself, I couldn't find a way to use `ng-if` on this element.

Answer (score 3):

Try `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

```
<ul class="dropdown dropdown-menu">
    <li class="menuOption" ng-repeat-start="option in options" ng-if="option.value>0">
      <a data-ng-click="option.value>0 ? foo() : goo()">
        {{option.value}}
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider" ng-repeat-end ng-if="option.value<0">
      option < 0 ({{option.value}})
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/3nmfKNk5SXH0meofg5sP?p=preview)